# Jenkins post build action notification throug skype

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, notifications, jenkins-plugins, skype

I have setup Jenkins on my amazon ec2 instance. I need to get build notifications to my skype id. Is this possible? I tried using skype-notifier plug in. I am totally confused with installation.

Actually, what is hudson slave/master?  What are the installation steps?